# Understanding PHP-FIG : PSR-3 (Logger Interface)

Tags: php, content-management-system

As a learning experience I am building a PHP based CMS using the FIG standards.  Can someone explain to me how I should integrate PSR-3 into my project.  I downloaded the source @ https://github.com/php-fig/log/tree/master/Psr/Log and I guess I am lost on how to proceed.

I don't understand what LoggerAwareInterface does.  Should I modify the above source to work actually log the data how I want or does this work as a wrapper to my own log class. Any help/information would be appreciate.

P.S. I should note that the best guide I was able to find was http://phpmaster.com/logging-with-psr-3-to-improve-reusability/ (specifically the section : Using PSR-3 to Avoid the Logger Dependency) and it still didn't click for me.

Comment: do you really need a logger for a CMS? I thought this would be better for daemons, cronjobs etc. (= cli scripts)

Comment: It might not be 100% needed but I would like one.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone searches and finds this I figured I should share what I've learned.

The answer I came up with is create a class called Log in your designated names space.  To make things easier I simply setup my class to extend \Psr\Log\AbstractLogger.  Because I did this I simply had to add a method called log with the params :

$level, $message, array $context = array()

If you didn't want do this simply create a class that has all the methods in AbstractLogger and then set it up to implment \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface

That's it.